# Aliasing an external dependency (zepto as jquery) with Rollup

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, rollup, zepto

jQuery is imported by `node_modules/backbone/backbone.js` but I need use [**zepto**](http://zeptojs.com/) instead of jQuery.

How can I edit the exported name of the zepto module to jquery?

**rollup.config.js**

```
plugins: [
    babel({
       exclude: ['node_modules/**', '**/*.html'],
       plugins: ['external-helpers']
    }),
    commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/**',
        exclude: ['node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**']
    }),
    resolve({
        jsnext: true,
        browser: true,
        main: true,
        module: true,
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    })  
],
file: 'build/build.js',
name: 'build',
format: 'umd'
```